# References - In what order should I start reading the books by Raymond Smullyan?

Tags: reference-request

The books by Raymond Smullyan have caught my fancy because they seem to teach mathematical logic using puzzles. However since I am very weak at solving puzzles in general and logic puzzles in specific, his books are giving me a hard time.

Could you please suggest in what order should I start reading his books so that the level of complexity is as gradual as possible? If you think that there is some other book/topic I should study first, please feel free suggest that as well.

Note - I don't want to start studying books on mathematical logic because I won't be learning to solve puzzle while doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest

> By date published

because that's the order he wrote them in, which makes the most sense to read them in, like a trilogy. His mind would develop new ideas with each book, and they are also a mind map.

[Raymond Smullyan publications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raymond_Smullyan#Selected_publications)

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: because that's the order he wrote them in, which makes the most sense to read them in, like a trilogy

Comment: But they're not an ongoing story. They're unrelated books.

Comment: well i would read them in that order

Comment: Can you explain why? Answers without explanation are deleted.

Comment: @Deusovi, Based upon my reading of first two-three chapters of the Smullyan's first book, it seems that they actually contain the easiest puzzles to get started with. This is in contrast with his later books where the first two questions just bounced off my head. I think he introduced the puzzles involving knights and knaves in that book. When a author introduces a new problem, he generally spends a good amount of time teaching that addition. This is just my observation and the second one might turn to out be the hardest but I am going to stick with these books anyway.